# Swift playground prose gone when changing file

Tags: swift, swift-playground

i tried to add

```
/*:
    Roses are `UIColor.red`,
    Violets are ,
    Swift Playgrounds are rad,
    and so are you!
*/
```

a very templetae prose onto my playground project, but when i tried to move onto another page or run the code, the prose vanish

is there a bug in the playground or is it just me???

i'm using Macbook M1 series

Answer (score 1):

When editing the playground, open the right tab of Xcode, and make sure the "Render documentation" option is checked on "Playground Settings". You can check the option to see the documentation and uncheck to edit the documentation.

[image]